# Optimal way to store a very large number of images in Visual Studio 13

Tags: .net, wpf, image, visual-studio

Okay, so I know how to store images in visual studio. Setting the build action to: Resource/Content and Copy to Output Direct: Copy if newer etc. I also know how to do this for a lot files.

**The problem** is that i have approx 2GB of image files that I at some point use in the application. So when i set the build action and copy to Output Direct for all these images, building the application really slowed down.

So i was wondering if there are a better or optional approach to having such a large number of image files in the project?

thanks, and sorry if this is a stupid question, but couldn't really find a satisfying answer to this.

Comment: But did you change these images? Why do you need them to be listed in your solution? Just copy them in their place, add them to your versioning system and forget about them unless you need to change something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2 GB it's no longer images that are part of the program, like an icon or a funny border, it's the application's *data*. Put it in a subfolder and treat it like any other data an application may need. Load it on demand, do not include it in your Visual Studio solution in any way.